# HP Proliant DL20 Gen9 not detect hdd boot after CentOS fresh install

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, centos8

I am a newbie in server world. My boss bought me an HP Proliant DL20 Gen9 server.
I am trying to install CentOS 8 on it.

Case :
I turned on the server and wait until initialization finished, then I pressed F11 to boot menu and I chose CentOS Linux. After installation wizard was shown, in partition section, I chose all to default since I only have 1 HDD (it shown ATA).  After installation finished, it rebooted. After system rebooted, I pressed F11 again to go to Boot Menu and I don’t find any boot using HDD, menus are same as first.

My question is why it didn’t boot automatically using CentOS installed? if can’t, how to get boot to CentOS that I have installed before?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go into the BIOS and configure what boot devices you'd like to use

Comment: how to go to BIOS? i am not sure but i like ever done it before but still no hdd bootable shown

Comment: i have tried it, and choose hdd, but it shown to install centOS again, any suggestion?

Comment: Then I'd guess there's something wrong with the CentOS installation, probably with the boot record of that drive. Do you have more than one drive in the server?